# Web API in MVC 6 is missing $id

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I have noticed that compared to Web API in MVC 5, where each object returned includes an $id property, in MVC 6 no such id is returned.  Since my client side code makes use of this property, is there any setting to enable it to be returned in MVC 6?

Comment: What you mean by `each item` ?

Comment: each object returned from what  ? Sorry i m still not able to understand your question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you formulate the question not full correctly, but I suppose that you can have the same result as before if you would modify `ConfigureServices` method of `Startup.cs`. Try to set `PreserveReferencesHandling` used by `Newtonsoft.Json` to the value `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
                PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        });
    ...
}
```

Such setting will don't add `$id` in really *all* object, but I think it should work in the cases, which you used before.